# Are ergonomics on topic for fitness?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been searching for a new chair to sit in at home, and I'm wondering if Fitness is the best place to ask ergonomic-related questions. I've search other Stack Exchange sites, and there doesn't seem to be a real place for these types of questions.

The [International Ergonomics Association](http://www.iea.cc/) defines "ergonomics" as:

> Ergonomics (or human factors) is the scientific discipline concerned with the understanding of interactions among humans and other elements of a system, and the profession that applies theory, principles, data and methods to design in order to optimize human well-being and overall system performance.

The Programmers Stack Exchange has some questions tagged with [ergonomics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics), most of which have been closed due to being off-topic (like this [chair question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17187/which-chair-do-i-buy)). However, there are some questions that are not closed which are related to ergonomics that don't fit the scope of "software development" as defined in their [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). I find this site too conflicting in that regard.

Personal Productivity has [one question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/98/do-ergonomic-keyboards-mice-provide-significant-productivity-improvement-over-av) currently but the context of ergonomics is related to productivity rather than health. There is a [meta question](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/ergonomics-on-or-off-topic) regarding ergonomics which has an answer suggesting it might belong on Fitness & Nutrition, but is probably better suited for Productivity on the reasoning that ergonomic experts would fit better there rather than here.

I am not looking for chair recommendations specifically since there is already a question on [choosing a chair for good posture](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/769/choosing-a-chair-for-good-posture), others related to using an [exercise ball](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=exercise%20ball) as a chair, and Jeff Atwood's blog post on [Investing in a Quality Programming Chair](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/investing-in-a-quality-programming-chair.html). My question is regarding any type of ergonomics in general being on-topic for this site. From what I've seen so far, I lean towards yes, but does this topic skirt the border between [fitness and general health](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/where-does-fitness-stop-and-general-health-start)?

Comment: Btw I upvoted your question, because I think its good that you brought it up no Meta, not because I agree with it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm guilty of 'pimping' the chair for good posture question, I actually think it would be a bad idea to let the site move further towards general health or ergonomics.

The fact that these questions aren't welcome on any other site shouldn't really matter, we aren't the trashcan of other SE-sites and get to define our own scope.

I would much rather see us cover **more diverse types of exercise and sports**, which is the whole purpose of the site, rather than diluting the scope with topics that are only related to Fitness.