# Tag sitting and questions about sitting

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I raised tag sitting: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tags/sitting/info

> Use tag sitting for questions about ergonomics, ergonomic chairs,
>   sitting positions and questions about potential damage to your body
>   caused by sitting for longer periods of a time.

One of my questions about sitting position was considered as off-topic. I'm thinking about it, searching... and I've found:

[Are ergonomics on topic for fitness?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-ergonomics-on-topic-for-fitness)

It looks like we should totally remove this flag. Any opinions? (Can someone do it, please?)

Answer (score 3):

Removing the tag from the question should be sufficient. Tags are also automatically cleaned up if the tag exists on one question for some amount of time (I believe it is 6 months if I recall correctly). Banning and blacklisting the tag requires action from the Community Team. Given the way the tag is currently worded, I do not see a reason for having this tag. If there are questions about "sitting" that are related to some physical fitness routine, I would imagine there are likely better terms to use than just "sitting."

I considered your question off-topic because its wording sounded like it was purely about sitting. The connection to what your exercise routine was not there, but you've provided some context for it. I simply thought you were just asking about sitting in a chair in that particular position for a long amount of time. I don't think what you are asking is quite off-topic since you could make the stretch relevant to running or volleyball but not sitting. You are welcome to edit your question accordingly. However, in your other comment you do ask what the cause of your pain in your hip might be which is off-topic.