# Questions about maintaining healthy eyesight welcome here?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day/186#186), I was about to ask a question about how to maintain or improve my eyesight, especially as a Database Admin/Dev who spends plenty of time in front of the computer. However, it looks like wellness questions are generally [not welcome](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/reviewing-the-site-scope-balance-between-fitness-and-nutrition) here.

Is that correct? Should I wait for [this Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health) to go live and ask there?

Or should I just talk to my doctor? :)

Comment: Just phrase it properly: "What's a good home exercise for toning my ciliaries?"

Comment: FYI there is a [health SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2) that is in commitment phase.

Answer (score 5):

If there is some connection to "fitness" then you're on topic. Generally speaking though, [wellness questions](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/where-does-fitness-stop-and-general-health-start) don't belong on the site. My question on [ergonomics](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-ergonomics-on-topic-for-fitness) was deemed to be off-topic as another example.

Robert Cartaino's [answer](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/recover-from-injuries-illness-posts-are-these-considered-fitness-nutrition/19#19) regarding [injury/illness recovery](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/recover-from-injuries-illness-posts-are-these-considered-fitness-nutrition) is good criteria for determining what is on topic and what is not.

> **On Topic**
>
> - **Dealing with exercise-related injuries are on topic.**
>     *"I pulled a muscle running. Apply heat or cold?"*
> - **Working around health-related issues in the context of reaching
>     physical fitness, on topic.**
>     *"I have allergies. What is a good exercise to replace my morning jog
>     when I can't go outside?"*
>
> **Off Topic**
>
> - **General medical/health "recovering from illness" questions (unless
>     there is a significant "physical fitness" component), off topic.**
>     *"What are the best remedies to speed up recovery from a cold?"* — off
>     topic

[Medical questions](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/medical-questions/132) shouldn't really belong on this site either, but it depends on the nature of it. Again, I would refer to Robert's answer. If you have to ask whether you should see a doctor or ask us (where there aren't any doctors at all), then you should go see a doctor. There's nothing stopping you from submitting to the "Health" proposal on Area 51.

Comment: Great breakdown +1