# Can we/should we be monitoring obviously poor planning?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm referring to this question: [Marathon - How to train for a marathon in 12 weeks?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/marathon-how-to-train-for-a-marathon-in-12-weeks)

It is in all likelihood, a recipe for disaster/injury. The poster accepted a very risky plan as an answer, what is the possibility that the site could be held liable for any possible claims coming out of this?

Or do we have as a responsibility monitoring the various bad ideas that people intend on trying? I know there are several posts/comments saying it's a dumb idea, but it's nagging at me a bit.

Comment: See also this other related [question about injuries](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/17/recover-from-injuries-illness-posts-are-these-considered-fitness-nutrition) and [Robert Cartaino's answer](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19/241).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know to what degree Stack Exchange or any of us can be held liable for posting answers here. Physical fitness of any kind inherently carries some risk of injury, and to quote [Robert Cartaino's answer](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/241) from another question:

> Like anything else you read on the internet, there's a degree of
>   responsibility and caution that falls on both the askers and
>   answerers.
>
> [F]olks answering questions shouldn't throw around wild generalities
>   when the author has not provided sufficient information.

If anything should be done, answers should be based on personal experience or be referenced by a credible source. The purpose is to follow the ["Back It Up! Principle"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and cut out the opinion to create an answer that is informative and helpful.

In terms of the question you linked, I see that some personal experience and risk of injury has been added. Comments on either the answer or question to extract more information from both sides would be extremely helpful in terms of making the question more specific and objective so that a *better* answer can be provided.