# Medical advice and injuries related to exercise

Tags: discussion, scope

I don't understand why https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/19252/3806 was closed as off-topic. The question deals with an exercise-related injury, which is on topic according to https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/3806 . So why did the question get closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the treatment was perceived as too medically-specific to be reasonably answered here, even though the injury was exercise-related?

Technically, it is "on hold" not "closed" so editing to garner re-open votes is possible.

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not vote to close, just speculating on why others felt this way

Comment: That's the way I was looking at it too. NSAIDs also (I think?) have connective tissue weakening properties, but a discussion of that quickly becomes a medical debate and leaves the fitness realm behind.